# Why put things in a tuple only to immediately get them out?

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen this in many places in the .NET framework. Unfortunately, I can't remember the others but they are all in the Katana source code assemblies.

Stuff is put into a tuple and immediately removed / read back out in the same method. This doesn't make any sense to me.

I understand (and also from reading [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) on the subject and having learnt the meaning when studying relational data many years ago) its uses. Just that this particular behavior does not make much sense to me.

```
public AuthenticationResponseChallenge AuthenticationResponseChallenge
{
    get
    {
        Tuple<string[], IDictionary<string, string>> challengeEntry = this.ChallengeEntry;
        if (challengeEntry == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new AuthenticationResponseChallenge(challengeEntry.Item1, new AuthenticationProperties(challengeEntry.Item2));
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            this.ChallengeEntry = null;
            return;
        }
        this.ChallengeEntry = Tuple.Create<string[], IDictionary<string, string>>(value.AuthenticationTypes, value.Properties.Dictionary);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, sorry, bad example. I've been working too long. I need to an example that illustrates my point. Unfortunately, I've rummaged through so much since morning that I can't remember and will get back to this when I can.

Answer (score 1):

In that way, the original tuple `this.ChallengeEntry`, isn't changed when the set / returned tuple changes.

Along the way, it keeps references to the original items in the tuple, but not the tuple itself.

Comment: Possibly also guarding against multi threading issues between checking if it's `null` and using the values contained within?

Comment: it checks if `challengeEntry` is null.  If you didn't make a copy of `this.ChallengeEntry` before getting to `return new AuthenticationResponseChallenge(...`, something else might null it out just before you try to use `this.ChallengeEntry.Item1`

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, was looking at the wrong code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, you have two properties that work together: `AuthenticationResponseChallenge` and `ChallengeEntry`.  They can both be accessed at any time, but the values need to be analogous.

The `AuthenticationResponseChallenge` is calculated from the `ChallengeEntry`.

I can't answer for why the authors of any library make the design decisions that they do.  I can say that the built in `Tuple` is convenient for temporary storage when you need any number of values associated together and you don't need the semantics of a dictionary.

In this particular instance, I personally would have done one of two things:

- Create my own struct/object with meaningful names for the member elements and a `ToAuthenticationResponseChallenge()` conversion method and a constructor that accepts an `AuthenticationResponseChallenge` object.
- Create an extension method or function that does the conversion.